# What do different Quartz TriggerState enum states represent?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

What do different Quartz TriggerState enum states represent and how do they get set?

I have a Spring 3.1 Quartz 2.0.1 utility used to run scheduled jobs. My jobs only repeat a fixed number of times. I expect that my TriggerState to go to COMPLETE when all the jobs are done. However, I see it go from NORMAL to NONE and I never see COMPLETE. I couldn't find much documentation on TriggerState behavior.

Relevant Java code:

```
SchedulerFactory schedFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

Scheduler scheduler =  = schedFactory.getScheduler();
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
scheduler.start();

while (System.in.available() == 0) {
    // Get trigger state
    TriggerState triggerState = scheduler.getTriggerState(triggerKey);
    if ((triggerState == TriggerState.COMPLETE)) {
        break;
    }
    // Sleep for 100 msec
    Thread.sleep(SCHEDULER_SLEEP_TIME);
}
```

Job configuration in Spring xml:

```
<bean id="mockJobDetail"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
  <property name="jobClass"
            value="mypackage.MockJob"/>
</bean>

<bean id="simpleMockJobTrigger"
      class="org.quartz.impl.triggers.SimpleTriggerImpl" >
  <property name="name" value="simpleMockJobTrigger" />
  <!-- run every 50 milliseconds and start immediately, run 3 times -->
  <property name="repeatInterval" value="50" />
  <property name="startTime">
    <bean factory-bean="dateFormat" factory-method="parse">
      <constructor-arg value="2012-01-01" />
    </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="repeatCount" value="2" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From looking at the code, it looks like the TriggerState goes to `COMPLETE` state and is then immediately removed from all tracking hash maps. That is why `scheduler.getTriggerState(triggerKey)` returns `TriggerState.NONE` -- this state is returned when the trigger corresponding to the `triggerKey` does not exist.

So, to check the completion of a trigger, it is possible to do:

```
if ((triggerState == TriggerState.COMPLETE) || (triggerState == TriggerState.NONE)) {
  // do stuff }
```

OR

to use a custom `TriggerListener` that does something when the trigger is complete.